# SQL - how to get all subcategory products incl. self products

Tags: mysql, sql, database, select

I have a problem with my database and I hope you can help me with this.

I have tables like this:

```
categories 
--------------------
|id | name | parent|
____________________

categories_x_products (m:n)
---------------------
|id | ctg_id | p_id |
---------------------

products
------------
| id, name |
------------
```

And my question is: "how to get all my & subcategories product count?" 
For example:

categories:

```
id = 1, name = computers, parent = 0 (1 product)
id = 2, name = notebooks, parent = 1 (2 products)
```

and I want to get

```
computers : 3
notebooks : 2
```

I try this but does not working

```
select a.name, count(b.id)
FROM categories a
LEFT JOIN categories x ON x.id=a.parent
LEFT JOIN category_x_product b ON b.ctg_id=a.id
group by a.id
```

Thank you for answers.

Here is some example data:

```
-- Adminer 4.2.3 MySQL dump

SET NAMES utf8;
SET time_zone = '+00:00';
SET foreign_key_checks = 0;
SET sql_mode = 'NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO';

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `categories`;
CREATE TABLE `categories` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `parent` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

INSERT INTO `categories` (`id`, `name`, `parent`) VALUES
(1,     'computers',    0),
(2,     'notebooks',    1),
(3,     'lenovo',       2);

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `products`;
CREATE TABLE `products` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

INSERT INTO `products` (`id`, `name`) VALUES
(1,     'lenovo thinkpad 001'),
(2,     'lenovo thinkpad 002'),
(3,     'lenovo thinkpad 003'),
(4,     'lenovo thinkpad 004'),
(5,     'lenovo thinkpad 005'),
(6,     'random comp.');

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `product_x_category`;
CREATE TABLE `product_x_category` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `product_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `category_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

INSERT INTO `product_x_category` (`id`, `product_id`, `category_id`) VALUES
(1,     1,      3),
(2,     2,      3),
(3,     3,      3),
(4,     4,      3),
(5,     5,      3),
(6,     6,      1);

-- 2016-02-23 08:16:30
```

Comment: What's not working about it

Comment: Give some more samples of data.. I don't understand how you want to get count 3 and 2 for this input

Comment: When i have 0 products in main category na 10 in subcategory.. this select returns me 0 in main and 10 in sub

Comment: I build example data for you -  http://pasted.co/517cccec my sql code now returns me "computers - 1, lenovo - 5, notebooks - 0" but i want to get "computers - 6, notebooks - 5, lenovo - 5" I don't know how to explain this better @sagi

Comment: Post it here, can get inside this web

Comment: ok, I just edit my post now)

Answer (score 1):

I've tried to run your SQL Query (Create table and insert value).

And I run this query

```
SELECT a.name, COUNT( b.id ) 
FROM categories a
LEFT JOIN product_x_category b ON b.category_id = a.id
GROUP BY a.id
```

And it returns this

[image]

This is your **product_x_Category** table (where category_id --> 3 = lenovo and category_id --> 1 = computer)

[image]

I think the result is what you want, isn't it?

Comment: I doubt it will matter

Comment: @СергейТитов Hi, I've tried to crete the table and insert the value into it, and actually your return query is all right. See my edited post aboe

Comment: yes, of course I do not want this result because notebooks and lenovo are subcategories so result what I want is "computers = 6, notebooks = 5, lenovo = 5" - computers have 1 product (but have subcategory notebooks thay have also 0 but notebooks have also subcategory lenovo (5 products) so 5+1 = 6 and the same way to calculate notebooks and others @Webster

Comment: @СергейТитов ya I know, but in your table, how can we know that computers have subcategory notebooks and notebooks have subcategory lenovo. I mean your tables don't have appropriate foreign key.

Comment: So, database design is my problem? What's about "parent" colum? It can't be used? @Webster